# mysql fastest way to get max value under specific threshold

Tags: mysql, subquery

I've got two tables and a slow query in mysql.

The tables:

1. Table clips with fields channel,start_time,end_time
2. Table shows with fields channel,start_time,end_time

both tables have indeces for field start_time.

I am trying to find the show that started just before the clip for many clips.

So far I've got this query:

```
SELECT (
   SELECT shows.id 
   FROM shows
   WHERE shows.starttime<=clips.starttime AND shows.channel=clips.channel
   ORDER BY shows.starttime DESC
   LIMIT 1) as show_id,
   clips.*
FROM clips
```

For a small number of clips this works great but for large number of clips it gets too slow.

My understanding would be that the dependent subquery should be extra fast since there is an index on start_time and all that needs to be done is an index lookup. Nevertheless it is slow and explaining the query states "using where" instead of "using index".

Here is the output of explain

```
--+------------------+-----+-----+------------+---------+------+----+------+-----------------------+
id| select_type      |table|type |possibleKeys| key     |keylen|ref |rows  | Extra                 |
--+------------------+-----+-----+------------+---------+------+----+------+-----------------------+
 1|PRIMARY           |clips|range| startDate  |startDate| 8    |NULL| 9095 |Using where;Using index|
 2|DEPENDENT SUBQUERY|shows|index| startDate  |startDate| 8    |NULL|287896|Using where;Using index|
--+------------------+-----+-----+------------+---------+------+----+------+-----------------------+
```

Any suggestions on how to improve performace for this task would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try to rewrite the query as

```
SELECT max(shows.starttime) as show_start, shows.id as show_id, clips.*
FROM shows
INNER JOIN clips ON (clips.channel = shows.channel AND shows.starttime<=clips.starttime)
GROUP BY clips.id
```

Because clips are part of a show, you would expect them to be close together, you can limit the number of hits further by doing something like:

```
SELECT max(shows.starttime) as show_start, shows.id as show_id, clips.*
FROM shows
INNER JOIN clips ON (clips.channel = shows.channel 
  AND clips.starttime BETWEEN shows.starttime AND DATE_ADD(shows.starttime, INTERVAL 1 DAY) )
GROUP BY clips.id
```

This will prevent MySQL from running a full subquery with sort on every row of clips.

Answer (score 0):

I think adding an index that uses both `start_time` and `channel` columns may improve the query performance to an acceptable value.

Johan's answer is great, but given your filters I think the index may improve the performance in any case.